# How to show the value of a field in an object when debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing Java program in eclipse 4.3 (Kepler). As the figure 1 shows, when the cursor hovers on an object, it prompts the value of the object. But if the cursor is on the field of an object, the variable value doesn't show. (Figure 2)

[image: when the cursor hover on an object, it prompts the value of the object]
Figure 1

[image]
Figure 2

Visual Studio however can show the value of an expression, see figure 3.
[image]
Figure 3

Is there anyway to make eclipse to show field value of an object when my cursor hovers on it?

Comment: I hope there is... I've found this very annoying as well (as a fellow C# + Java programmer).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is different for the debugging, you have to search for your variable in another frame like presented [here](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/tips-and-tricks-debugging-ecli)

Comment: You mean Detail Formatter? It is a possible workaround but still not as convenient as in Visual Stduio.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a tutorial with your answer.

http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/tips-and-tricks-debugging-ecli